# How can you create your own array of colors in google go?

Tags: go

I don't want to use the standard color palettes in the go language, so I am wondering how can you create your own color palette.

Comment: You should expand your question. As it stands, we don't really know what kind of color palette you are asking about. The one of your IDE? The ones from the `image/color/palette` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the project [lucasb-eyer/go-colorful](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful), which can generate color palettes.

```
pal1, err1 := colorful.WarmPalette(10)
pal2 := colorful.FastWarmPalette(10)
pal3, err3 := colorful.HappyPalette(10)
pal4 := colorful.FastHappyPalette(10)
pal5, err5 := colorful.SoftPalette(10)
```

> The following picture shows the palettes generated by all of these methods (sourcecode in **[`doc/palettegens/palettegens.go`](https://github.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful/blob/master/doc/palettegens/palettegens.go)**), in the order they were presented, i.e. from top to bottom:
>
> - Warm,
> - FastWarm,
> - Happy,
> - FastHappy,
> - Soft,
> - SoftEx(isbrowny).
>
> All of them contain some randomness, so YMMV.

[image: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lucasb-eyer/go-colorful/master/doc/palettegens/palettegens.png]

Comment: That's fantastic! Wow I will so totally use this.